# WooCommerce Admin product "general data" postbox issue

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, backend

I have strange problem with woocommerce product data options. Instead of opened by default, mine is closed on page opening.

I tried with this function to remove "closed" class, but without success. Any advices for this?

```
add_filter( "postbox_classes_product_woocommerce-product-data", 'product_postbox_data_open' );
function product_postbox_data_open( $classes ) {
    array_splice( $classes, 'closed' );

  return $classes;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I can’t find a description or documentation for a filter named `postbox_classes_product_woocommerce-product-data`, and neither can I find this in the code base of a current WooCommerce. Where did you get this from?

Comment: @CBroe I see second answer here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94401/auto-close-hide-custom-metabox-set-default-state/94406

Comment: That’s _eight_ years old, so probably not applicable any more to a current WooCommerce version.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't noticed date.
Will search for another solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove from `wp_usermeta` for your `user_id` the row that has `closedpostboxes_product` as meta key, via phpMyAdmin…

You can also do it running once this function (by browsing any page as an admin):

```
add_action( 'init', function(){
    if( current_user_can('administrator') ) {
        delete_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'closedpostboxes_product' );
    }
});
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Remove it after usage.

Comment: Thank you, i will check your solution too!

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**
This is a way, i resolved my problem :)

```
   add_action('admin_footer', 'disable_metabox_folding');
        function disable_metabox_folding()
        { ?><script>
        jQuery(window).load(function() {
           jQuery('.postbox').removeClass('closed');
        });
        </script><?php
    }
```